# Pandas multiiindex boolean slice

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'm so new to this I don't have the vocabulary to properly frame the question.  Nor do I know how to include the output very well.

I'm trying to slice a multi indexed dataframe of COVID19 data.  I want to select data from countries other than China.  I know how to slice using a multiindex based on countries I want to see, I just don't know how to look at everything but a country or set of countries.

```
                     1/22/20   1/23/20   1/24/20...
Country   Province  
China      Hubei       28        28         28
Italy       NaN         0         0          0
...
```

Obviously the dataframe is much bigger.  All I want to do is slice by excluding rather than explicitly including.

`df.loc['China']`

Gives me all rows with China.  How do I slice to exclude?  Below doesn't work, but it gives the idea:

`df.loc[!='China']`

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0) != 'China']
print (df1)
                  1/22/20  1/23/20  1/24/20
Country Province                           
Italy   NaN             0        0        0
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.  And after reviewing [get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values) I understand how it works!